# R: compute the length of text data in a column

Tags: r

I have the following csv data `myData`:

```
   name   attribute
1  Name1  attr11,attr12,attr13
2  Name2  attr21
3  Name3  attr31,attr32
```

I want to plot the distribution of the number of attributes, to do that I need to loop through each row, and tokenize the data in the column `attribute`, and count the length. Essentially, that should give a vector or another data with the same length as the original `myData`

I have tried:

```
num_attr <- length(as.list(strsplit(myData$attribute, ",")))  #this just returns 3
```

and:

```
num_attr <- as.list(strsplit(myData$attribute, ","))
```

this returns a list something like:

```
["attr11" "attr12" "attr13", "attr21", "attr31" "attr32"]
```

I am also thinking of using `apply()`, like `apply(myData, 1, func)` but I am not sure what `func` to put in.

In summary, how do I plot the distribution/density of the number of attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `strsplit()` is a list, so if you want the number of elements in each split you should use an `*apply` function. Try this:

```
num_attr <- sapply(strsplit(x = myData$attribute, split = ','), length)
```

this applies `length()` to each list element (each split) and returns a vector of length N (where N is the number of rows in myData).

If you want `num_attr` as a list do:

```
num_attr <- lapply(strsplit(x = myData$attribute, split = ','), length)
```

Comment: there is the shorthand `lengths` for this as well, `lengths(strsplit(myData$attribute, ","))`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Been using R for 5 years and this is the first time I see `lengths()`. Nice. Maybe I should call myself 'jenesaispastout'.

Comment: it was added a few years ago, maybe around R 3.2 or so -- lol!

Answer (score 2):

We can also count the number of `,` in the 'attribute' column

```
library(stringr)
str_count(myData$attribute, ",") + 1
#[1] 3 1 2
```

#### data

```
myData <- structure(list(name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3"), 
 attribute = c("attr11,attr12,attr13", 
"attr21", "attr31,attr32")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```